# Stocktwits Api Endpoint for users was removed?

Tags: stocktwits

There was an endpoint that I was using on my system which no longer works (HTTPS):
api.stocktwits.com/api/users/show/75992.json
Apparently it no longer exist.

I took a look on their documentation (e.g http://stocktwits.com/developers/docs/api#streams-user-docs) and I couldn't find such endpoint.

And we have a similar API endpoint, which works (HTTPS):
api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/user/75992.json

Since I couldn't find Release Notes neither the History of the API, I couldn't tell it was removed. Can someone tell me if that endpoint was removed?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Pierce here from StockTwits.

You are correct, we've decommissioned the old version of our API and the updated documentation that you're looking for is here: http://stocktwits.com/developers/docs/api#streams-user-docs

There are minor updates to the new API endpoint, including first & last name merger. Bust most everything should be the same. Let us know if we can help further - api@stocktwits.com.

Comment: Thank you very much Pierce! I just wanted to confirm this information. I am updating my system accordingly. Cheers!